# Can't find the source of a DatabaseObjectNotClosedException error

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having a hard time figuring out what my problem is here.  I'm receiving this error in my program, but it does not cause a crash or anything like that.  I have an update I'd like to release, but I don't want to release it with this error being thrown at certain times.  I've read all related posts on this error, but none apply to my situation.

I've made sure that I am closing my DatabaseHelper and SQLiteDatabase objects.  I've also made sure that I'm closing all of my cursors.  This error is pointing toward my method getActiveScheduleInfo, which returns a Cursor object.  I've made sure that whenever I call this method, the returned cursor is closed in a Finally block.

Is this incorrect to do it this way?  In my methods that call getActiveScheduleInfo, I have multiple return statements in them, based on certain conditions.  So, instead of closing the cursor before each return line, I surround the condition testing with a Try, and close everything down in my Finally.

Everything looks like it should be working, so I'd really appreciate any help!

Thanks a lot!
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out!  I hope that this helps someone else out there having the same problem.

I wasn't doing anything inherently incorrect here, but was rather taking too long to close some of my cursors.  To give you a very brief background, I could not use a Managed Query or use startManagingCursor, since this code was in a custom class, not an activity.  I am building against Android 2.0 (API level 5) so I am not using the new CursorLoader object.

I was taking the following steps:

1. Opening the database.
2. Creating a new Cursor and performing my query.
3. Iterating through the cursor and performing the needed tasks
4. Performing some other logic
5. Closing the Cursor and Database in a Finally block.

I found out that my step 4, performing some other logic, coming before closing my Cursor, was causing it to, for lack of a better term, timeout and cause this error.  From now on, I read the necessary data from the Cursor, and not ONE LINE OF CODE FURTHER, I close the Cursor.  :)   This has completely eliminated these random errors, and I have clean-running code again.

I hope that helps others having the same problem!  Take care,

Paul